# Is there is any way to get the mobile phone number using bluetooth?

Tags: mobile, java-me, bluetooth, jsr82

This is my friend's interview question.

Is there is any way to get the mobile phone number using Bluetooth?. There is a mobile phone A it connect with the another mobile phone B through Bluetooth. How to get the mobile phone  number of B in Mobile phone A via Bluetooth.

The above situation is possible in j2me ?

Comment: Im not only asking in j2me.I want to know the above situations is possible in .NET,Android,Iphone,etc.Here i want to develop a mobile app which get the another mobile number via bluetooth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its **not** possible using java-me

Comment: Jigar joshi.Thanks for ur reply.Im added some additional points in my query.Please refer it and give me valuable ideas

Comment: Even including all your additional points: if this was possible it would be a severe security problem. I doubt the guys constructing phones will make it this easy.